# Automatically mounting windows share in Fedora 12

Tags: linux, fedora, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to automatically mount a windows share in a Fedora 12 instance (FC12).

When I manually mount things work:

```
mount -t cifs //nas01/servers -o username=guest,password=myPassword /mnt/nas01/servers
```

If I update /etc/fstab with the following:

```
//nas01/servers /mnt/nas01/servers cifs username=guest,password=myPassword 0 0
```

Nothing happens after reboot.

The thing that has me baffled is after a reboot if I run:

```
mount -a
```

The share is mounted.

Any ideas on this?

Thank you,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that when your fstab is processed all required prerequisites aren't in place to mount the network share.

You can try adding the mount command to your rc.local startup script.

Answer (score 1):

From `man 8 mount`:

> FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS
>   _netdev
>                 The filesystem resides on a device that requires network  access
>                 (used  to  prevent  the  system  from  attempting to mount these
>                 filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).

Answer (score 1):

Fedora has a script `netfs` that parses fstab a second time during boot once the network is up to mount shares:

> `chkconfig netfs on`